# My table doesn't show up

Tags: php, html

I have the following code, and the tutorial I followed says that the table should show up, but it doesn't. All that shows up is the text inside the `<h1>` and `<h4>` tags, and the external CSS file is also not taking effect. The code I have is as follows:

```
<?php
include_once('connection.php');
$query="select * from myanimelist";
$result=mysql_query($query);
?>

<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="styles-2.css">
</head>
<body>
<h1> Callum Stewart's Amazing Website. </h1>
<h4> The Home of Entertainment. </h4>

<table align="center" border="1px" style="width: 300px" color="black">
    <tr>
    <th>Anime Database</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <th>Title</th>
    <th>MediaType</th>
    <th>Rating</th>
    <th>NumOfEpisodes</th>
    <th>NumOfVolumes</th>
    </tr>
</table>
</body> 
</html>
```

Comment: Just caught the `<?php>` thing and fixed the quotes, but still doesn't work.

Comment: Do you mean there is not data placed in the table after the headings?

Comment: Check your server error logs for potential errors, and maybe enable [PHP error reporting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1053424/how-do-i-get-php-errors-to-display) for your local development environment

Comment: @RiggsFolly The only data that appears on the page is the two headings. That's it. No table.

Comment: Do you know what version of PHP you are using on your server

Comment: where is your <form> tag?

Comment: @briskovich Why does OP need a form when he is only showing data

Comment: @RiggsFolly I don't. How do I find that information?

Comment: Are you running on a loca (yourown) server of a hosted server

Comment: @RiggsFolly - I just always include a form tag in every .php page I build. I have a blank template that I use over and over. I got OP's page to load up just fine. Of course it won't display anything as written now but it works.

Comment: Ditto, I get a table as well, but I removed the php tags and code

Comment: I'm running on localhost, yes.

Comment: Make a script containing just `<?php phpinfo(); ?>`

Comment: Did you find out the PHP version you are using yet?

Comment: Are you using windows or *nix

Comment: I am using Windows, and PHP version 7.2.1.

Comment: The `mysql_` API was removed in PHP7 gone forever. You will have to start using the `PDO` or `mysqli_` API's to access MySQL databases now

Comment: I am using `mysqli_` but nothing is changing.